# Is there any good reason to enable both full-disk and home-directory encryption on a single-user machine?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, luks

The installer invites you to do both, so I did, but home-directory encryption is making backups and recovery more complicated, and I suspect that it might be redundant.

Comment: I think you are right, disk encryption provides the main protection, I would not encrypt home in a single-user machine.

Answer (score 0):

For some situations, yes. Both gives you:

1. Protection when your system is turned off through whole-disk encryption.
2. Protection against other `sudo` users and applications running as `root` *when you're logged out* through home folder encryption.
3. [Your home directory gets tighter permissions when you use home folder encryption](https://askubuntu.com/a/107327/616451), though you can set these permissions yourself to get that benefit without encryption.

Home folder encryption is less important *if you already use whole-disk encryption* when you're the only user on the system, since the files are automatically decrypted anyway by the system whenever you're logged in, and you're probably going to be logged in whenever the system is turned on.